# Is there a way to setup REPL to always pprint?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I found myself wrapping expressions in pprint way too often. Something tells me that there's an option somewhere to do this automatically, but I can't find it. So, instead of typing this:

```
(pprint list-of-maps)
```

I would like to just type

```
list-of-maps
```

in the REPL and get the pretty printed output.

Comment: See also `pp`, which does a `(pprint *1)`. So, you don't have to remember to wrap first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use

```
(clojure.main/repl :print pprint)
```

Found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/ydtWuNrq_6I).

From the [docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.main/repl):

> **repl clojure.main**
>
> *(repl & options)*
>   ...
>       - :print, function of one argument, prints its argument to the output
>       default: prn
>   ...